# How to create and stop a wanted number of setInterval and stopInterval?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to do a for loop which allows me to create a wanted number of setIntervals, but there is a problem with the clearInterval.

I want to stop only one setInterval but if I want that, I believe that I have to put all setIntervals into variables right ?

But the problem is that the number of setInterval can change and I don't want to do a switch for each value of this number and declare too many variables, it will be endless.

Is there another way to stop setIntervals one by one ?

My code :

```
var width = 0;
var progress;
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        url : 'controller/game/ajaxProgressGame.php',
    }).done(function(data){
        for(let i = 0 ; i < data.length - 1; i += 2)
        {   
            goProgress = setInterval(function(){
                progressBarChose(data[i],data[i+1])
            },10);
            /*setTimeout(function(){
                clearInterval(goProgress);
            },1100);*/
        }
    });
});

function progressBarChose(idGame,percentage)
{   
    if(width >= percentage )
    {       
        clearInterval(goProgress);
    } else {
        width++;
        $('#progressBar'+idGame).css('width' , width +'%' );
        $('#progressBar'+idGame+' p').html(Math.floor(width) + '%');        
    }
}
```

I want to change the clearInterval(goProgress) to clearInterval one by one, because here it's clearing all intervals, and I don't want to use clearInterval in setTimeout.

Thank you !

Comment: you can put them into an array.

Comment: It's working ! I didn't even know about an array what a shame... Thank you